# How to make an efficient to-do-workflow for back-end staff?

Tags: user, best-practice, workflow

CiviCRM is very flexible, to be able to be adjusted to the needs of many different use cases. One thing that is not set up by default, but is very helpful, is to set up to-do-lists for staff member.

**What is the best practice for setting up a to do workflow?**

(On the site I am administering, we have separate reports, showing for scheduled and pending activities last three months, with a certain assignee name. These reports are displayed on the dashboard of each user. At the same time the cron job will send by email daily reports with only the scheduled activities. So, each user can change the activity status from scheduled to pending, to indicate that they are working on it.)

Answer (score 1):

We've set up custom reportlets on dashboard that list the upcoming activities for the current user ordered by due date.